# Images resize when exporting them to SVG from Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, svg, resize, image-quality

lately I have been encountering a frustrating problem about **keeping quality of images from Illustrator (v14.0.0) to Microsoft Word (2016)**. I created a mixture between PNG images, vectors and texts in illustrator. When I try to keep its quality I fail miserably: either something moves or the quality drops.

My first approach was to export the images to SVG and then insert them into word. When I do so the initial PNGs I cropped change in size (justa  little bit bigger, enough to mess everything up). This screenshot shows the original image from illustrator:

[image: Screenshot from illustrator]

And this is the result of exporting it to SVG:

[image: Screenshot from SVG already inserted in Word]

As you can see, the quality is almost the same, except for a small drop, but the images changed in size. Neither changing the artboard's size nor the text to outlines solved the problem. 
The configuration while exporting to SVG is the following (I'm sorry for it not being in english):

[image: Configuration of SVG export]

In case it helps, when I changed the SVG profile to "SVG Basic 1.1" it did keep the images in place, but the quality dropped drastically. Searching for solutions I found that copy-pasting from illustrator to word works wonders and keeps the quality, but still some dashed lines suddenly turn into solid ones among other minor details. **Is there a way to export to SVG without the images changing and keeping the native quality**?